# Trying to find solution for ODE with power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Consider the equation $$y'-y=e^x$$$$y(0)=0$$ Using power series, I'm supposed to find $y(x)$. So far, I got that
$$y'-y-e^x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n x^{n-1} -\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n -\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=$$$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)a_{n+1}x^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty 
 x^n[(n+1)a_{n+1}-a_n-\frac{1}{n!}] =0$$
which follows that $$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{a_n}{n+1}$$
The textbook answer states that $y(x)=xe^x$ (which I know should be in the form of its power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n!} $). By writing down the terms, I got that $a_1=1, a_2=1, a_3=\frac{1}{2},a_4=\frac{1}{6}\dots$ but I can't see the pattern that leads to $xe^x$. Can I have some assistance? :)

Also, as an addendum, the only way I was taught solving was doing this way, which always leads to some $a_{n+1}=a_n$ recurrence which I need to solve. Is there some other way which doesn't require solving the recurrence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$
a_{n+1} = \frac{1+n!a_n}{(n+1)!}.
$$
and $a_0 = 0$.

> Claim: $a_n = \frac 1{(n-1)!}$

This is true for $n=1$. Assume that it is true for some $n$. Then
$$
a_{n+1} = \frac{1+n!a_n}{(n+1)!} = \frac{1+n}{(n+1)!} = \frac 1{n!}.
$$
Done.

Comment: Nice. But how did you see it? I have some problems in solving the recurrences

Comment: Well, you said the answer is $xe^x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}$... ;-)

Comment: Without knowing the answer I find it hard to see...

Comment: When you know the sequence $(n!) = (1,1,2,6,24,\ldots)$, you see it immediately.